# Arrow keys spontaneously stop working in vim

Tags: vim

I recently upgraded from OS X 10.6 (I think) to 10.9. Since then it seems, while editing in `vim`, the arrow keys will "spontaneously" stop working.

At one point, in frustration I "mashed" one of the arrow keys and was *eventually* shown a "E388 Couldn't find a definition" error. All other times I've experienced it, the arrows, having worked for awhile, suddenly start *dinging* at me!

Quitting and reopening solves the problem *temporarily*. But, I'd like to *prevent* it!

Anyone know what this might be? And how to fix it?

---

It looks like my default `vimrc` was modified during the update. If my memory is correct, it was a pretty big file previously. Now, it just contains this:

```
" Configuration file for vim
set modelines=0         " CVE-2007-2438

" Normally we use vim-extensions. If you want true vi-compatibility
" remove change the following statements
set nocompatible        " Use Vim defaults instead of 100% vi compatibility
set backspace=2         " more powerful backspacing

" Don't write backup file if vim is being called by "crontab -e"
au BufWrite /private/tmp/crontab.* set nowritebackup
" Don't write backup file if vim is being called by "chpass"
au BufWrite /private/etc/pw.* set nowritebackup
```

I have no idea what these options do yet. I'll look into it -- but, hopefully someone here knows more quickly than I can google and read ...

Comment: I also just realized there's an Apple-centric forum here that this question might be better suited for. So, if this is more likely a condition of OS X than `vim`, perhaps a mod could migrate this for me.

Comment: Reminds me of working on a "Prime" mainframe in college.  The professor taught that you should never use the arrow keys in `vi`. Always use hjkl. That's where the "arrow" keys use to be on ancient hardware.

Comment: OK... But, the arrow keys should work. Regardless of whether your professor thinks I should use them. And I find them convenient at times. So, looking forward to see the solution.

Comment: what happens when you insert the key literal into a buffer?  go into insert mode, and press Ctrl+v, then an arrow key.  Vim on my Mac shows the up arrow key as `^[OA`, down as `^[OB`, right as `^[OC`, and left as `^[OD`.  check before and after the problem presents itself

Comment: @NathanWallace not sure how I overlooked your question. I'll try that when I'm at my Mac next.

Comment: Things to try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812973/linux-vi-arrow-keys-broken-in-insert-mode

Comment: @NathanWallace The best I can tell you right now is that I get the same results *before* the issue occurs. I can't reliably reproduce it. It occurs randomly, as far as I can tell. It'll happen multiple times in succession, and then won't happen for days.

Comment: @NathanWallace It happened again, *seemingly* after saving a file. (Perhaps a *similar* sequence triggers it?) After it occurred, my arrows were up: `^[[A`;, right: `^[[C`; down: `^[[B`; left: `^[[D`;. Is that helpful?

Comment: Those key values don't match up to anything I can figure out.  I wondered if maybe one of your modifier keys was getting stuck or something, but those key values don't match up to my arrow keys with any modifiers.  Sorry I couldn't help!  I guess just get used to hjkl, which is way better anyway :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Found in [James Hodgkinson's blog](https://yaleman.org/2013/02/11/e388-error-in-vim-on-osx/), the following command works for me. Note it will refresh the vim screen.

```
:!reset
```

Comment: Not sure how I overlooked this answer, but it looks very promising!

Comment: In fact ... Hitting Ctrl+R as described in the article reproduces the issue in full consistency with the wrong arrow-key mappings noted in my response to Nathan above. And the reset command solves it in that case. *And* .. I can't reliably reproduce the problem any other way, so this is definitely the most useful answer!

Comment: does not fix the problem for me, but I do think the Cmd+R (OS X in my case) is what gets me into this state. Running inside screen

Comment: FWIW, I had the arrow key problem only in VIM inside screen, other windows in the same screen session were working. Disconnecting and reconnecting the screen session fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 22):

I have run into this problem a few times as well. I happened to be running GNU screen on another computer that I was logged in to via SSH. To fix the problem, I detached my screen(s) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd>), logged off of the machine, logged back in, and reattached using `screen -x`. It may work without logging off of the machine, just by detaching and reattaching screen. I cannot remember though.

Comment: Closing my screen session and restarting it fixed it for me.

Comment: that was the problem for me. Somehow `screen` got in a state of funk (over an ssh connection). Closing that terminal, then ssh again, and `screen -rd` did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @PierreD correct, I've run into this issue a few times already as well - also in a `screen` session, Detach & Reattach solved the problem, thanks!

Comment: For me I think it was triggered by the GPG tty agent being launched from vim in a screen session - detach / reattach fixed it.

Answer (score 13):

In the path `/usr/share/vim/` I found the `.vimrc` file... There I added the line

```
set term=ansi
```

It worked for me. Now the arrow keys are working properly in Vim editor.

Comment: This fixed it for me too, since latest Windows 10 WSL/Ubuntu update broke it.

Comment: Worked for me but add the above in home directory ~/.vimrc

Comment: This worked for an Ubuntu Docker instance using Docker Toolbox Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds very much like your issue. The article is titled: [Cursor Keys in Vim: You Mac’ing Me Crazy!](http://viget.com/extend/cursor-keys-in-vim-you-macing-me-crazy).

*excerpt*

> Vim is useful in many situations, particularly for quick edits (especially as root), and editing files on a remote server. One annoyance I've had during my nine months with a Mac Book Pro is cursor keys in Vim ringing the bell in both insert or command mode instead of changing lines. Upgrading to version 7 via MacPorts yielded the same results. The cursor keys worked after switching my TERM to VT220 from rxvt! The downside was syntax highlighting stopped working.
>
> Luckily, adding VT220 to my Google search parameters turned up a reference to vt100-cursor-keys in the Vim documentation. Add the following code to your .vimrc file to fix the problem:
>
> ```
>     :set notimeout          " don't timeout on mappings
>     :set ttimeout           " do timeout on terminal key codes
>     :set timeoutlen=100     " timeout after 100 msec
> ```

In the same article there's another suggestion of setting your `$TERM` to `linux` instead on OSX.

*excerpt*

> A better solution is to change the default value for TERM to either linux or dtterm since the TERM value will be picked up on the remote server. In this day and age, I would bet most servers support both these terminal types.

Comment: Hmm ... I'm even more confused now. I'd thought I had global/default `.vimrc` files. Would these have been moved or removed during an OS X update?

Comment: @svidgen - No I don't think that would've changed, but that issue sounded er-rely similar to yours, and the fix is easy enough to try out, so I thought I'd share it with you. Incidentally the `$TERM` could've gotten changed on you.

Comment: Whelp, this is definitely the most relevant answer here. +1 for that. Not sure whether it fixes it yet, unfortunately, since I can't consistently reproduce the problem.

Comment: After having applied this fix, the issue has occurred again. Still a relevant answer, leaving the +1. But, please see my comment above if you're interested in supplying an additional answer.

Answer (score 0):

Congrats on the update.  I did my own update over the weekend and have been dealing with some of my own odd keyboard issues.

Here are a couple of things I needed to to:

- Remove old Logitech gaming software and upgrade.  Prior to doing this I was having issues using my square and curly braces. Special keys often send esc-[ sequences in the VIM context so this might be relevant.
- Go into System Prefs:Security and Privacy:Privacy:Accessibility and enable a couple of apps (synergy_server and Logitech gaming software).  Prior to this change I was unable to control my other computers with synergy or use macros with my G11.  I doubt this is a direct connection for you but the Accessibility options are new and might apply to some other app of yours.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in `.sql` files in `vim` (you don't mention) this could help you. I just dealt with this the other day.

In file `~/.vimrc`

> `let g:omni_sql_no_default_maps = 1`

this particular issue is discussed [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1572)

If you're not experiencing this problem with `.sql` files in `vim` then I apologize, my only thought would be to verify the mapping within `vim` when the problem occurs.

`:map Ctrl V →`  when you lose your ability to use your arrow, do that command and see if the mapping disappeared. if it did, this gives you a place to start digging in.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in an SSH session and solved it by logging out then back in again:

```
exit
ssh ...
```

Comment: Thanks for weighing in. The selected answer has consistently worked for me though. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, the accepted solution didn't work on Ubuntu 18. I even uninstalled and reinstalled vim (in the same ssh session) and no dice. Only logging out then back in again restored arrow functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I used a "system environment variable" in Windows, setting `TERM` to `xterm-256color`. The issue went away (and my `vim` returned to normal) when I deleted the variable again.